# Probability Interpretations

Tags: probability

How comprehensive is the following book - What interpretations are missing?

Interpretations of Probability, Andrei Khrennikov, 2009, de Gruyter, ISBN 978-3-11-020748-4

http://www.degruyter.com/cont/fb/ma/detailEn.cfm?isbn=9783110207484&sel=pi

Contents:http://www.degruyter.com/files/pdf/9783110207484Contents.pdf

Comment: I don't think it is a valid question here; just check out wiki and references there: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_interpretations

Comment: That wikipedia article is filled with "dubious-discuss" and other tags, so the question would become how comprehensive is that wiki article, what interpretations are missing from it.

Comment: Still references are quite informative. And nevertheless even if it is discussive and mentions something that is not present in the book it is some kind of a clue, isn't it?

Comment: See the meta thread: http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/213/list-of-candidate-questions-to-be-closed where this question is proposed to be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Though quantum probability and negative probability models are quite interesting, this is hardly exhaustive of nonstandard models of probability.  There are for instance, [imprecise probability models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imprecise_probability), and models that violate Kolmogorov's countable additivity axiom, and more.

As an aside, the book may be more properly called 'Models of Probability'.  [Interpretations of probability](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/probability-interpret/), generally involve characterizing the competing understandings of probability as logically prescribed values, limiting frequencies, propensities, subjective beliefs, etc.   Models, or axiomatizations can certainly be motivated by these understandings, but the problem of creating a variant system is different than arguing for a particular interpretation.